# add +1 for month indexing in pickadate

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pickadate

I want to disable all dates excepting from range of start_date and end_date for eg : date start from 26/05/2015 to 29/05/2015 so all the dates before start and after end get disable. For this I am using pickadate and pickadate month indexing start from zero.

```
$('.datepicker2').pickadate({
        format: 'dd/md/yyyy',
        selectMonths: true,
        selectYears: 25,
min: [$("#leave_start_date").val().split("/").map(Number).reverse()],
max: [$("#leave_end_date").val().split("/").map(Number).reverse()]
});
```

but it is not working. It disable all dates remaining current date.
Please guide me how to solve this. I want to disable that dates only who is not coming in range of start_date and end_date values.

Comment: are the leave_start_date and leave_end_date values coming from pickadate? or these are from other text fields?

Comment: these aretwo other textfields with pickadate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the first issue is that the values for `min` and `max` can take an array like `[2014,05,26]` but with that `map`, I suspect you're sending an array nested in an array `[[2014,05,26]]`

```
'15/05/2015'.split('/').map(Number)
JS> [15, 5, 2015]
'15/05/2015'.split('/').map(Number).reverse()
JS> [2015, 5, 15]  <<<<< this is what (i think) pickadate wants
['15/05/2015'.split('/').map(Number).reverse()]
JS> [Array[3]]    <<<<< this is what (i think) you are sending
```

Also, as you mentioned in the title, the month counter that `pickadate` expects starts at 0.  With a little helper function like this

```
function formatDateForPickadate(date_string) {
  vals = date_string.split('/').map(Number).reverse()
  vals[1] -= 1
  return vals
}
```

you can do:

```
min: formatDateForPickadate($("#leave_start_date").val()),
max: formatDateForPickadate($("#leave_end_date").val())
```

And the offset month will get fixed properly.

Comment: When I made the first cut, I didn't realize the month offset was also part of the issue.  Glad this worked out.